# View element of a DialogFragment layout is not accessible by id

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-library, dialogfragment

I have a custom DialogFragment whose layout holds just a EditText element.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reminder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reminder_message"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class ReminderDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reminder, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (onDismissListener != null) {
        String text = (String) ((TextView) (rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder))).getText();
        onDismissListener.onDismiss(text);
        }
    }
```

It is working fine in app module. But I want to take into library module. But then I debugged the error, it is because 
R.id.reminder is 0.

Is there anyway to access the element.

Comment: What you want to do?  Why you accessing it in ondismiss

Comment: I am long pressing a map marker's InfoWindow and that opens a DialogFragment having an EditText element. I don't want to have any submit button. As soon as user closes the dialog, text is set in InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getDialog().findViewById() instead of rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder)

**

> EDIT

**

try to use

[Resources.getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can do

**getResources().getIdentifier("res_name", "res_type", "com.library.package");**

In your case:

R.id.reminder would be:

**getResources().getIdentifier("reminder", "id", "com.library.package");**

Comment: getDialog() is returning null

Comment: It won't work because R.id.remainder is coming to be 0

Comment: try to use [Resources.getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  You can do getResources().getIdentifier("res_name", "res_type", "com.library.package");  in your case:

R.id.reminder would be:

getResources().getIdentifier("reminder", "id", "com.library.package");

Comment: check imports of your R.class, maybe your R imported from out of your library

Comment: Hi Ognev, I checked. But that is not the problem. Can you please have a look at the code. I can send you that on mail if you don't mind. Please send me empty msg on kuldeep5534@gmail.com

Thanks,

Comment: I made my repo public, have a look.
https://bitbucket.org/kuldeepiitg/location-alert

Comment: i've found a problem, your problem in cast of types :)    replace 47 line in ReminderDialog with this line  String text = ((TextView) (rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder))).getText().toString();

Comment: and make build->clean and rebuild :)

Comment: No brother, That is not the problem. Try debugging the code. You will get the issue is with id not typecast.

Comment: i debugged and found just string cast exception, after fix it worked....  strange but it working on my phone

Comment: my logs with test message in dialog is 06-19 00:10:19.191    7986-7986/com.palup.locationalert I/Place Chooser﹕ test

Comment: This is strange, certainly. I am planning to move the fragment to app module where it works.

Comment: Wait! what did you do to reproduce the bug? The steps are as following :
1. Select a place in Place Autocomplete Text box.
2. Now, click the map marker, it will show InfoWindow.
3. Long press the InfoWindow, it will open a text dialog. Write some text there.
4. Dismiss the dialog by pressing outside the the text box. Now it will execute the OnDismiss and throws error.

Comment: I checked in one more environment, no difference.

Comment: I moved DialogFragment from library to app module. So it is working fine now. But thanks a lot for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the Dialog instance supplied and then find the view:

```
((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.reminder);
```

Don't forget to cast to the appropriate type of Dialog you are using but in general Dialog should work out.

Comment: It won't work because R.id.remainder is coming to be 0,

Answer (score 0):

The method `onCreateView` is useless for DialogFragments.
You should override:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), null);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_reminder);
    return dialog;
}
```

Then, as Ognev Zair pointed out, you can use `getDialog()`:

```
String text = (TextView) (getDialog().findViewById(R.id.reminder))).getText().toString();
```

Comment: It won't work because R.id.remainder is coming to be 0

Answer (score 0):

I also checked out your solution. There isn't any problem with the view id! If it's there it is related to your local setup. So please run:

```
gradlew clean
```

and then build the project again. 
The only error I got is related to a wrong cast you are doing when retrieving the text input:

> 06-19 10:38:29.602 7974-7974/com.palup.locationalert E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.palup.locationalert, PID: 7974
>                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                              at
>   com.palup.library.fragment.ReminderDialog.onDismiss(ReminderDialog.java:47)
>                                                                              at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1323)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

So just update your code within the ReminderDialog:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (onDismissListener != null) {
        String text = ((EditText) (rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder))).getText().toString();
        onDismissListener.onDismiss(text);
    }
}
```